# could not able to open the gallery after connecting to a webservice

Tags: android, web-services, video, gallery

I can connect to a webservice but what I want to do is after connecting the webservice I want to open the gallery and choose a video from there. Could you please help me where is the problem?
here is my code:

```
package com.isoft.uploader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UploaderActivity extends Activity 
{

//ArrayList<Response> WebData= new ArrayList<Response>();
public static final int SELECT_VIDEO=1;
public static final String TAG="UploadActivity";
String path="";
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String SERVICEURL = "http://192.168.10.177/androidws/isandroidws.asmx";
final String METHOD_NAME1="OzelVeriAlanlariniGetir";
final String METHOD_NAME="KullaniciGiris";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Enter);
    final EditText username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //request code for Webservice
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //sending the username to the webservice
            request.addProperty("kullaniciAdi",username.getText().toString());
            //sending the password to the webservice
            request.addProperty("password",password.getText().toString());
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            //Putting the request in an envelope
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICEURL);
            try
            {
                 transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
                 //getting the response from the webservice
                 Integer response = (Integer) envelope.getResponse();
                 if(response!=0)
                 {
                    openGaleryVideo();
                 }//end of if statement
            }//end of try 
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }//end of catch

        }//end of onClick method
    });//end of OnclickListener method
}//end of onCreate method


public void openGaleryVideo()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),SELECT_VIDEO);
}//end of openGaleryVideo method

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{   
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}//end of getPath method
}//end of main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution:

```
package com.isoft.uploader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UploaderActivity extends Activity 
{

//ArrayList<Response> WebData= new ArrayList<Response>();
public static final int SELECT_VIDEO=1;
public static final String TAG="UploadActivity";
String path="";
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String SERVICEURL = "http://192.168.10.177/androidws/isandroidws.asmx";
final String METHOD_NAME1="OzelVeriAlanlariniGetir";
final String METHOD_NAME="KullaniciGiris";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Enter);
    final EditText username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    final  AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //request code for Webservice
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //sending the username to the webservice
            request.addProperty("kullaniciAdi",username.getText().toString());
            //sending the password to the webservice
            request.addProperty("password",password.getText().toString());
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            //Putting the request in an envelope
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICEURL);
            Object response = null;
            try
            {
                 transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
                 //getting the response from the webservice
                 response= envelope.getResponse();
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }//end of catch
            if(response!=null && Integer.parseInt(response.toString()) != 0)
            {
                openGaleryVideo();
            }
            else
            {
                ad.setMessage("Lütfen Kullanıcı Adınızı ve Şifrenizi Kontrol Ediniz.");
                ad.show();  
            }

        }//end of onClick method

    });//end of OnclickListener method
}//end of onCreate method
public void openGaleryVideo()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),SELECT_VIDEO);
}//end of openGaleryVideo method

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{   
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}//end of getPath method
}//end of main
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Android class AsyncTask can be helpfull.

make the WebService request on doInBackground method and show the gallery on postExecute method.

more info: [AsyncTask on Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**Update:**
Replace the onclick method content with:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>(){

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //request code for Webservice
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //sending the username to the webservice
        request.addProperty("kullaniciAdi",username.getText().toString());
        //sending the password to the webservice
        request.addProperty("password",password.getText().toString());
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        //Putting the request in an envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICEURL);
        try
        {
             transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
             //getting the response from the webservice
             return (Integer) envelope.getResponse();
        }//end of try 
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }//end of catch
        return 0;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if(result!=0)
        {
           openGaleryVideo();
        }//end of if statement
    };
};
```

Comment: But I need to use AsnycTask while uploading too. Can I use this more than once in the app?

Comment: what about the arguments? what should I use as arguments in this situation?

Comment: In the example code of the question the Ws returns an Integer, so for example AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>, the String are params to the doInBackground method and the Integer the response of this method and the param of the onPostExecute method.

Comment: could you plesa show me in the code or corrected version? Because I am a bit confused. @sabadow

Comment: Sorry but it does not connect anymore to the webservice too. @sabadow

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13786/discussion-between-answer88-and-sabadow)